# recursion in Dr Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am making a simple code that uses recursion for printing the elements of a list:

```
(define (printList list)
  (if (empty? list)
      '()
      (begin
        (display (car list))
        (printList (cdr list)))))
```

It actually works, but I want to know if there is a way that does not print the empty list. When I run my program with (printList '(1 2 3 4)), I got:

1 2 3 4 ()

Any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this just to practise recursion? Because the better (and more standard) way to do what you're doing is simply `(for-each display lst)`.

Comment: `DrScheme` changed name in 2010 to `DrRacket`. [Consider upgrading](http://racket-lang.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output you have consists of

1. the `display`s : `1234` (color: pink)
2. the result of the function : `'()` (color: blue)

Dr Racket will not print the result of the function if it is `void`, so you could return `void` in your base case:

```
(define (printList list)
  (if (empty? list)
      (void)
      (begin
        (display (car list))
        (printList (cdr list)))))
```

but it would be more elegant to say

```
(define (printList list)
  (unless (empty? list)
    (display (car list))
    (printList (cdr list))))
```

which will return `void` implicitly if the list is empty and doesn't need an explicit `begin`.